# Is golden section search considered a fitting (regression analysis)?

Tags: regression, fitting, reproducible-research

I am curious if the [Golden section search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) is a form of fitting (or [regression analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) in general)?

It does find the extremum, but independent of any functional form (it works without modeling, if I am not mistaking). It is also iterative, so I am a little confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an optimisation technique for unimodal function so highly dependent on functional form. It's not a regression method but might be made into one by vectorising it's inputs and minimising least squares or something similar.